# facebook app id required error

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to reach and use what this guy explained here  http://qnimate.com/wordpress-frontend-facebook-login/ so i can allow the log in using facebook account. I followed the instructions of adding button, i uploaded the php file to it's path and made the button using the link procvided there.
i made facebook app and i added the both  app id and secret key in the inc/facebookoauth.php 
and here is it's code:

```
function facebook_oauth_redirect()
{
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require_once("../wp-load.php");
//construct URL and redirect
$app_id = get_option("facebook_app_id");
$redirect_url = get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_callback";
$permission = "email,name";

$final_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . urlencode($app_id) . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url) . "&scope=" . $permission;

header("Location: " . $final_url); 
die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_facebook_oauth_redirect", "facebook_oauth_redirect");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_oauth_redirect",   "facebook_oauth_redirect");

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}

function facebook_oauth_callback()
{
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query, $wp_rewrite, $wp_did_header;
require_once("../wp-load.php");

if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{   
    $token_and_expire = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . get_option("facebook_app_id") . "&redirect_uri=". get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=facebook_oauth_callback" . "&client_secret=" . get_option("facebook_app_secret") . "&code=" . $_GET["code"]);

    parse_str($token_and_expire, $_token_and_expire_array);


    if(isset($_token_and_expire_array["access_token"]))
    {   
        $access_token = $_token_and_expire_array["access_token"];
        $user_information = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . $access_token . "&fields=email,name");
        $user_information_array = json_decode($user_information, true);

        $email = $user_information_array["email"];
        $name = $user_information_array["name"];
        if(username_exists($name))
        {
            $user_id = username_exists($name);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            update_user_meta($user_id, "facebook_access_token", $access_token);
            header('Location: ' . get_site_url());
        }
        else
        {
            //create a new account and then login
            wp_create_user($name, generateRandomString(), $email);
            $user_id = username_exists($name);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            update_user_meta($user_id, "facebook_access_token", $access_token);
            header('Location: ' . get_site_url());
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        header("Location: " . get_site_url());
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: " . get_site_url());
}

die();
}

add_action("wp_ajax_facebook_oauth_callback", "facebook_oauth_callback");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_facebook_oauth_callback", "facebook_oauth_callback");
```

so you can see both "facebook_app_secret" and "facebook_app_id" there where i added the both codes. So when i try and clic on the button it gives back this error says The parameter app_id is required.
what the matter in ur opinion?

Comment: nobody knows whats wrong?